# Time intervals as strings python

Tags: python, string, variables, time, range

Im pretty new at programming and right now I'm working with Zoo in python, a programme where the user can put in a time interval by choice during the opening hours of the zoo. The Zoo is open from 07-23, and for example the bear is available from 08-18 to look at.
for example.
What time do you wish to visit the Zoo?
input by user: 10-13

At this time you can see the animals:
...
...

And the programme will write out exactly what animals are available for show at that time interval. Given our example, the bear will be available and be printed out.

Im wondering how I can easy make the programme translate the input by the user to a string or maybe with range, so I dont have to create a hundred different varibles like 06-06, 06-07, 06-08, 06-09 etc.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking "How do I take a variable `a` that contains `"06-08"`, and get two variables `b` and `c` that contain `"06"` and `"08"` respectively?": `b,c = a.split("-")`

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll probably want to convert each string to to integers, a start time and an end time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this by changing the ask a little bit to the following:

> What time will you arrive at the Zoo? **9 am on 11/11/2015**
>
> How long would you like to stay? **3 hrs**

This will let you use a nice date picker widget on the front end which you can then create a [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for the start. Next, create a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object for the duration. You can apply the delta the the start object to get the end time so you don't have to worry about parsing.

The other reason I recommend this is anecdotally I've seen evidence that users perceive start and duration and more clear/easier to use rather than picking two times. Per the above, you plan on spending 4 hours at the Zoo, not being there specifically from X to Y, so this UI better matches the mental model.

Comment: You are making things complex, why he needs a datepicker when he has consideration for a single day?

Comment: I don't think that's complex for a number of reasons: 1, it's a common library UI widget he can use without doing his own validation. 2, it's something users are familiar with interacting with and know how to use. 3. It provides a full date to build a datetime object rather than just having an arbitrary integer that he has to derive meaning. He's working with dates and times and should work with that data as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can store each interval as a pair of integers corresponding to the start/end of the time interval:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Interval = namedtuple('Interval', 'start end')
```

If you have a string such as `'10-13'`; you could convert it to `Interval`:

```
user_hours = Interval(*map(int, '10-13'.split('-')))
# -> Interval(start=10, end=13)
```

To find out *"what animals are available for show at that time interval"*, you need to know whether two given time intervals intersect:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    return a.start < b.end and b.start < a.end
```

Example:

```
>>> intersect(Interval(8,18), Interval(10,13))
True
```

There are no overnight intervals and therefore you could treat the time intervals as linear (intervals on a line).

Now, you only need to populate the table with visiting hours for zoo animals:

```
visiting_hours = {
    "bear": Interval(8, 18),   # 08-18
    "lion": Interval(14, 16),  # 14-16
}
```

and you can print which animals are available for the given user hours:

```
for animal, available_hours in visiting_hours:
    if intersect(user_hours, available_hours):
        print(animal)
```

---

As an alternative you could use `datetime.time()` instead of `int` to represent hours -- it enforces valid values (0..23) for hours automatically:

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:
   user_input = input("Input time interval e.g., 10-13: ")
   try:
       user_hours = Interval(*[datetime.strptime(h, "%H").time()
                               for h in user_input.split('-')])
   except ValueError as e:
       print("Invalid input: %s. Try again." % (e,))
   else:
       break
```

Modify the "visiting hours" table accordingly:

```
from datetime import time

visiting_hours = {
    "bear": Interval(time(8), time(18)),
    "lion": Interval(time(14), time(16)),
}
```

You could automate the input e.g., by reading the visiting hours from a file.

The rest of the code stays the same.

---

You could save the visiting hours into a separate file e.g., SQLite database and edit the table independently (using another script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')  # create in memory for debugging
db.execute('''CREATE TABLE intervals
              (animal text, start integer, end integer)''')
# populate
visiting_hours = [('bear', '08-18'), ('lion', '14-16')]
db.executemany('INSERT INTO intervals VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
               [[animal] + list(map(int, hours.split('-')))
                for animal, hours in visiting_hours])
```

To get the animals from the database:

```
# "what animals are available for show at that time interval"
for animal, in db.execute('''SELECT animal FROM intervals
                             WHERE ? < end and start < ?''',
                          tuple(map(int, '10-13'.split('-')))):
    print(animal)
```